# Using a variable as a column name in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, view, haml

I'm trying to set up two environments for my site, one on a development server, one on a live one. And I want to dictate which records from the DB can be seen on each server. I've created a file in my includes, for development it has this `@show = "dev"` and for live it has `@show = "live"` I've included this at the top of my application layout so it is on every page. Then in my views, with each database call I want to put some conditions like this:

```
- f = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ["#{@show} = 1"])
```

But it doesn't pick  up `@show` as being the variable, just uses it explicitly or ignores it. Is there a simple way to do this or will this not work how I expect it to?

**update**

I've managed to make it work, but I have to include the file on each individual view rather than just on the application layout... Not ideal but it's a solution:

```
= render "includes/dev_live"

- f = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {@show => 1})
```

Comment: what is preventing you from having separate databases for each environment?

Comment: I don't want to have two copies of everything, that's how it was before and everything was out of sync

Comment: Using text substitution inside a query is kinda frowned upon, due to the possibility of SQL injection. I suspect it is unlikely that the value of @show can be changed by a malicious user, it is good practice to use the hash form for conditions (as in the two answers below)

Comment: I would suggest using the built-in rails environment accessor (`Rails.env`) rather than your own global variable.

Comment: Why would you need up-to-date data on development? And what is stopping you from dumping production db everyday into development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be better off changing your variables to symbols i.e

```
@show = :dev
@show = :live
```

then your active record query could become:

```
f = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {@show => 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert a Variable into instance variable. for using it in conditions.

You can try this

f = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {@show.to_sym => 1 })